# What is the best way to check if a bunch of variables are equal to some value? ie. are a,b,c,d are all equal to 3

Tags: javascript

I have a few variables, and if all of them are equal to 3, I will be executing another function.  Is there a performance hit, or is there a better way of doing this-

```
if (a === 3 && b === 3 && c === 3 && d === 3) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: use switch case instead

Comment: hi.  but when and only when all are 3, I want to execute a function.

Comment: @user1354934: Define "better". What's wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: i just wanted to know if the way i'm doing is nooby and if there is a better way.

Comment: Questions like this are better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl It's a bit of a grey area, but this question probably belongs on SO (if anywhere). It's too specific and too short to fit Code Review very well.

Comment: @Zak don't see why it's grey at all. The code works and OP is looking for alternatives

Comment: @charlietfl This is example code, which is explicitly off-topic at Code Review.

Comment: @charlietfl Those are necessary, but not sufficient, criteria for a good CR question. SO is for "specific programming questions", which I would argue this is.

Answer (score 2):

An obscure technique is to put all variables into an array and check with every.

```
if ([a, b, c, d].every(e => e === 3)) {
    // code for true
}
```

Comment: Given that OP was worried that their version was too slow, giving a slower approach doesn't seem like a good answer.

Comment: there is no way to speed up single varible checks.